# Set pose position to armature

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm having some problems with this model.
I created the armature using mixamo, and he also gave me the pose position.
As you can see in the pictures it is a T-pose and the inclination of the hands is different.
I would like to be able to apply the pose position as a new rest position (using the command "apply position position as rest position") but the result is that the model does not fit the skeleton.
I could recreate the model and its armor, but I want to know if there is any way to recover the model, if I were in similar situations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

tnx to all.

Comment: Just adding four screenshots doesn't help. What do they represent?

Answer (score 1):

It appears, that you want to apply your new pose to the model as well as the armature.

To do that, make sure you are in the desired new rest pose. Then apply the armature modifier on the object first. The object will now be unlinked from the armature, but it will be in the target pose.

*Now*, you can apply the Pose as Rest Pose to the armature. Following this, both (armature and mesh) have the desired pose as the default pose.

To clean up, re-add an armature modifier to the mesh and select the armature as the target object of the modifier.